# Data signed in C#, verifies in C# but not in Java

Tags: java, c#, digital-signature, sha256

I have signed data that I would like to verify in C# as well as Java. While it verifies fine in C#, it fails in Java (no exception, but the verification function returns false.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var publicKeyXml = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>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</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
            var data = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
            var signature = Convert.FromBase64String(
                "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");
            var rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsaKey.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);
            if (rsaKey.VerifyData(data, "SHA256", signature))
                Console.WriteLine("VERIFIED");
        }
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        String publicKeyModulus = "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";
        String publicKeyExponent = "AQAB";
        byte[] data = new byte[]{1,2,3,4};
        byte[] signature = Base64.getDecoder().decode(
                "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");

        byte[] mod = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyModulus);
        byte[] exp = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyExponent);
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(mod);
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(exp);
        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        s.initVerify(pubKey);
        s.update(data);
        if (s.verify(signature))
            System.out.println("VERIFIED");
    }
}
```

I found several similar SO posts, but could not find a solution. One mentioned the difference of BigInteger encoding between .NET and Java. I confirmed that the byte order is different: When reeversing the "mod" buffer in the java program (little endian -> big endian), before creating the BigInteger, the "modulus" is the same as in .NET (if I took the modulus out of the XML in .NET and converted it into a BigInteger). The exponent buffer reads 0x01 0x00 0x01, so it doesn't matter (same backwards and forward). But after doing that, the verification still failed.

Comment: I added the test data (data, signature, public key) and made it two single file console applications.

Comment: Replace `new BigInteger(mod)` with `new BigInteger(1, mod)`. This is essentially a duplicate of: [validating rsa signature from C# in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392586/validating-rsa-signature-from-c-sharp-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, that works, I can't believe I didn't see the other posting, it is indeed almost 100% the same.